# Smartsheet API - List sheets in a folder not implemented?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am using the Smartsheet 2.0 API with the C# SDK. I am trying to iterate through all of the sheets in folder. However, I am unable to find the API code to do so.

I tried FolderSheetResources interface, but a List() method isn't even implemented like on other interfaces; for example, WorkSpaceFolderResources.

```
smartsheetClient.WorkspaceResources.FolderResources.ListFolders() // Method exists.

smartsheetClient.FolderResources.SheetResources.ListSheets(); // Method doesn't exist.
```

And I have also tried the Sheets property of the Folder object.

```
folder.Sheets; // Always returns null.
```

**Does anyone know how to list all sheets inside a folder?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `getFolder` on the specific folder you're looking at.

```
Folder folder = smartsheet.FolderResources.GetFolder(
  7116448184199044,           // long folderId
  null                        // IEnumerable<FolderInclusion> include
);
```

Once you have this `Folder` object, you can take a look at the `Sheets` array property.

The [API Docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#folder-object) will give you more information about what else is present.